# Hide taskbar with Taskbar Eliminator

Tags: vbscript

With my tiny VBScript I'm trying to execute Taskbar Eliminator and run the key combination 'ALT + T' to hide the taskbar.
The program is being execute correctly but the key combination does not get recognized by the program.
Here's the code:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Dim strPath
Dim strKeyCombo

strPath = "C:\Taskbar_Eliminator.exe"
strKeyCombo = "%T"

WshShell.Run strPath, 1, true
WshShell.AppActivate "Taskbar_Eliminator.exe"

WshShell.SendKeys strKeyCombo
```

Maybe I'm just not seeing an obvious error but I'd be very glad if somebody could just point it out :)

Comment: Does it work if you press ALT+T manually? `SendKeys` will send virtual input, and Taskbar Eliminator might filter those out.